# How do I get rigify arm IK bones to no longer aim toward origin?

Tags: rigify, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

I am modeling a tennis player with rigify.  I have created several actions (forehand, backhand, etc), all of which work when tested alone.  I did them at the origin of the scene.  My problem is, when I try to move the rig around the scene (using an empty to which the rig is a childof), the arms (I'm assuming the hand IK control bones), always point toward the scene origin, no matter where I move the rig.

How do I get the arms to reference the rig itself (chest, torso, root...)?

Comment: hello, could you please show a screenshot, share your file, etc?

Comment: I have posted a blender file here.  If you grab the rig by the root, and move it in the XY plane, the IK bones of the hands always point to the center of the scene.  I tried parenting the IK arms to the shoulders, but to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.

http://www.capnetix.com/blender/BallLaunchScene_10.blend

Comment: After experimentation, I've discovered that the rigify Hand IK bones are parented to the Root bone, but the rest of the rig bones are not.  I have a suspicion of what might have happened.  I am wondering whether my using the Rigify Animbox "Turn Setup" which creates a ChildOf constraint may have messed up the parenting within the rig.  The hand IK bones parent to Root, but the rest do not.

Comment: Hello, I'm not familiar with Rigify and this kind of tools, so I'm often lost in the generated armatures. I guess the IK target and pole target bones should be parented to the root, I'm not sure about how your armature is done, I hope someone will answer.